# Self-deleting array elements (once they become undefined)

Tags: arrays, perl, oop, weak-references

I have a Perl script generating an array of weak references to objects.  Once one of these objects goes out of scope, the reference to it in the array will become undefined.

ex (pseudo code):

```
# Imagine an array of weak references to objects
my @array = ( $obj1_ref, $obj2_ref, $obj3_ref );

# Some other code here causes the last strong reference
# of $obj2_ref to go out of scope.

# We now have the following array
@array = ( $obj1_ref, undef, $obj3_ref )
```

***Is there a way to make the undefined reference automatically remove itself from the array once it becomes undefined?***

I want `@array = ($obj1_red, $obj3_ref )`.

### EDIT:

I tried this solution and it didn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    package Object;
    sub new { my $class = shift; bless({ @_ }, $class) }
}

{
    use Scalar::Util qw(weaken);
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $object = Object->new();

    my $array;
    $array = sub { \@_ }->( grep defined, @$array );

    {
        my $object = Object->new();
        @$array = ('test1', $object, 'test3');
        weaken($array->[1]);
        print Dumper($array);
    }

    print Dumper($array);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'test1',
          bless( {}, 'Object' ),
          'test3'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'test1',
          undef,
          'test3'
        ];
```

The undef is not removed from the array automatically.

Am I missing something?

### EDIT 2:

> I also tried removing undefined values from the array in the DESTROY method of the object, but that doesn't appear to work either.  It appears that since the object is still technically not "destroyed" yet, the weak references are still defined until the DESTROY method is completed...

Comment: Do you mean `my @array = ( ... )` or `my $array = [ ... ]`?

Comment: I meant `()`, I will correct it.  Sorry this is just some quickly written pseudo code, it's more just to get the point across than to be syntactically correct.

Comment: Quickly written pseudo-answer: clear the lists in the destructor of the objects. Or, use an object instead of the array that would clean itself before any operation that needs it.

Comment: You should post that as a real answer, the destructor method sounds like a good idea.  Upon destructing the object I can (probably) remove all undefined values from the array. :)

Comment: Re "the weak references are still defined until the DESTROY method is completed...", np. Search your a reference to yourself rather than undef.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say, could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean search "for" a reference to yourself? I think I get it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: I want to have some sort of parent object that can keep track of it's children in an array, but children can be destroyed unexpectedly and I want the array to be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, short of using a magical (e.g. tied) array.

If you have a reference to an array instead of an array, you can use the following to filter out the undefined element efficiently without "hardening" any of the references.

```
$array = sub { \@_ }->( grep defined, @$array );
```

This doesn't copy the values at all, in fact. Only "C pointers" get copied.

Comment: Would this essentially run the grep command whenever the array is accessed?  Sorry I'm not too familiar with code references and how they work.

Comment: You would run the command whever you want to clear the undefined values, yes.

Comment: What about the comment from ThisSuitIsBlackNot below, he claims that using grep on a weak reference converts it to a strong reference.  This would be a problem.

Comment: What he said is correct, but it's different than when you claim he said, so there's no contradiction between my answer and his comment.

Comment: I attempted your solution and it didn't appear to work.  Please see the details above.

Comment: Ohhh I see, your method is a function call that will need to be called every time I want to remove the values.  I was looking for a solution that would avoid that.  Perhaps choroba's comment might be the best solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Re "The undef is not removed from the array automatically. Am I missing something?", Yes, that I said that it can't be automatic, at least not without using a magical (e.g. tied) array.

Comment: Re "Perhaps choroba's comment might be the best solution", Yup. If the array members have a ref back to the object that owns the array, then this would be best.

Comment: This seems to be very picky... I noticed your change above, do I have to weaken the reference after I already put it in the array?  I tried weakening it before putting it in the array and it wouldn't become `undef` anymore.

Comment: Re "do I have to weaken the reference after I already put it in the array?", Yes. Like ThisSuitIsBlackNot pointed out earlier, a copy of a weak reference isn't weak. So if you want `$array->[1]` to be a weak ref, you need to weaken `$array->[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl won't do this for you automatically.  You have a couple of options.  The first is to clean it yourself whenever you use it:

```
my @clean = grep { defined $_ } @dirty;
```

Or you could create a [tie'd array](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Array.html) and add that functionality to the `FETCH*` and `POP` hooks.

Comment: The problem with the `grep` approach is that copying a weakened reference makes it a strong reference. From the Scalar::Util docs: "This may be less obvious in other situations, such as `grep()`, for instance when grepping through a list of weakened references to objects that may have been destroyed already: `@object = grep { defined } @object;` This will indeed remove all references to destroyed objects, but the remaining references to objects will be strong, causing the remaining objects to never be destroyed because there is now always a strong reference to them in the `@object` array."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot So would you have to `map` them back to weakrefs?